# In Half Blood Prince, Arthur Weasley tells Potter that the ministry raided Lucius' manor when he was arrested. How is it possible?

Tags: harry-potter

Why didn't they find Voldemort or Bellatrix there? If Bellatrix wasn't there, where was she? In the beginning of HBP, when Narcissa goes to Spinner's End, Bellatrix quickly apparates after her to stop her and that would imply that they were in the same house. If Malfoy Manor was so susceptible to raids, why was Bellatrix living there? Why did Voldemort made it his headquarters?

Comment: From what I recall of the beginning of Deathly Hallows it was implied that the Death Eaters were meeting at the Malfoy residence for the first time.  I don't think we know where Voldemort was hiding before that point, it doesn't really matter to the story.  Bellatrix may have simply been visiting Narcissa, or vice versa, just before the beginning of Half Blood Prince.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Death Eaters were almost certainly not there during the raid.

The raid which Mr Weasley describes took place in the summer of 1996, right at the start of *Half-Blood Prince*. He tells Harry about the raid and Lucius's arrest on Platform Nine and Three-Quarters as Harry is about to return to Hogwarts for year six. The first time we see Voldemort, Bellatrix and the other Death Eaters at Malfoy Manor is almost a full year later, in the summer of 1997 (when Harry was due to start year seven). It's probable that the Death Eaters wouldn't have been in the Malfoy residence during said raid.

Remember that Voldemort and co were still in hiding until right at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*. It's not clear where they were based during this time period, but it needn't have been in the Malfoy residence.

We know that Voldemort left the Malfoys effectively housebound because he was displeased with them. Picking their house as a base had as much to do with punishing them as it did anything else. He was displeased with Lucius's failure to retrieve the prophecy and with Draco's failure to kill Dumbledore directly.

> Scowling, Snape said, “The Dark Lord does not expect Draco to succeed. This is merely punishment for Lucius’s recent failures. Slow torture for Draco’s parents, while they watch him fail and pay the price.”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33, The Prince's Tale)*.</sub>

Voldemort probably only moved into the Malfoy residence (when he wasn't chasing the Elder Wand) once that second failure had occurred. When we see characters referring to the Malfoy manor they talk about it as if it was made a base only recently. Voldemort says that he has noticed Lucius being unhappy "of late", implying that Voldemort hadn't been living there that long.

> “I have given you your liberty, Lucius, is that not enough for you? But I have noticed that you and your family seem less than happy of late...What is it about my presence in your home that displeases you, Lucius?”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1, The Dark Lord Ascending)*.</sub>

Greyback knows that it's being used as a base - but only as a rumour. This implies that it wasn't a longstanding arrangement.

> “Will you summon ’im? *’ere*?” said Scabior, sounding awed, terrified.
>   “No,” snarled Greyback, “I haven’t got - **they say** he’s using the Malfoys’ place as a base. We’ll take the boy there.”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23, Malfoy Manor)*.</sub>

Yaxley also gets startled by a peacock when he approaches the building, implying that he wasn't familiar with the location and hadn't spent a lot of time there.

All in all, it seems likely that Voldemort and co 'moved in' to Malfoy manor around about the summer of 1997. Given that the Ministry raid was a year earlier than this, this simplest explanation for why the Ministry didn't find them is that they weren't there.

Comment: I suppose The Dark Lord would know.

Answer (score 1):

## They could Disapparate before the raid.

Even if Bellatrix, the Dark Lord, or both, was staying at Malfoy Manor when Lucius Malfoy was arrested and the manor was raided, whichever of them was there could have Disapparated before the Ministry arrived, since they both are capable of it. Bellatrix can Apparate - she Apparates to follow Narcissa to Snape’s house.

> “With a second and louder pop, another hooded figure materialised.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 2 (Spinner’s End)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord is also able to Apparate - he Apparates out of the Ministry of Magic building to escape capture.

> “He was there!’ shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was pointing at a pile of golden rubble on the other side of the hall, where Bellatrix had lain trapped only moments before. ‘I saw him, Mr Fudge, I swear it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and Disapparated!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 36 (The Only One He Ever Feared)*</sup></sub>

They’d be safe once they Disapparate, because it’s impossible to track anyone who Apparates.

> “They explained what had happened; when they had finished, Lupin looked aghast.
>
> ‘But how did they find you so quickly? It’s impossible to track anyone who Apparates, unless you grab hold of them as they disappear!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11 (The Bribe)*</sup></sub>

Because of this, Malfoy Manor being raided wouldn’t make it an unsuitable hideout - if the Ministry came knocking at the door, they could just Disapparate. The Ministry wouldn’t be able to ambush them by Apparating into Malfoy Manor, since wizard houses usually are protected against unwanted Apparators.

> “Professor, why couldn’t we just Apparate directly into your old colleague’s house?’
>
> ‘Because it would be quite as rude as kicking down the front door,’ said Dumbledore. ‘Courtesy dictates that we offer fellow wizards the opportunity of denying us entry. In any case, most wizarding dwellings are magically protected from unwanted Apparators. At Hogwarts, for instance –’
>
> ‘– you can’t Apparate anywhere inside the buildings or grounds,’ said Harry quickly. ‘Hermione Granger told me.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4 (Horace Slughorn)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, Bellatrix, the Dark Lord, or both of them could stay at Malfoy Manor without being captured when the Ministry raided it, or during any subsequent raids.

## It’s also never said they *were* there then.

Additionally, it’s not clear that either Bellatrix or the Dark Lord were actually staying at Malfoy Manor at the time of Lucius’s arrest and the raid. It’s never explicitly stated that either of them were staying there from that early on, and at the Death Eaters’ meeting in Malfoy Manor, Bellatrix mentions that it’s an honor to have the Dark Lord in her family’s house, which would be an odd statement for her to make then if he’d been staying there for more than a year before that meeting took place.

> “My Lord,’ said a dark woman halfway down the table, her voice constricted with emotion, ‘it is an honour to have you here, in our family’s house. There can be no higher pleasure.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, it’s not certain that either Bellatrix or the Dark Lord would have been in Malfoy Manor to begin with to even require them to Disapparate due to the raid.

Comment: Also at the point the Death Eaters were meeting at the Malfoy's, Voldemort had control of the Ministry of Magic so no raids...

Comment: The Ministry could presumably block Apparition, like the Death Eaters did in Hogsmeade: *The air through which they needed to move seemed to have become solid: They could not Disapparate; the Death Eaters had cast their charms well.*